# "vulgarem latinum accentu italico pronunciatum sed est"

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

In the comment section of "[Shakespeare's Julius Caesar in LATIN · Act I Scene 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amAFuz5az70)" by ScorpioMartianus, one can read the following comment:

> vulgarem latinum accentu italico pronunciatum sed est

I think that this is (very bad) Latin for "But Vulgar Latin must be pronounced with an Italian accent". So just for fun, I tried to write it with correct grammar:

> Sed lingua latina vulgaris accentu italico pronuntianda est

How latinate is my attempt?

**Edit** I know that the statement itself is nonsense, I am just asking about the grammar/vocab.

Comment: I say what you wrote is correct. I'm not sure why the commenter put the subject in the accusative.

Comment: I believe Vulgar Latin is generally called *sermo vulgaris*. Also, *accentus* does not mean "accent" in the sense of a regional variation; Smith & Hall suggest *sonus* for that (e.g. *sonus subrusticus*), but I would perhaps prefer *more Italico* in this context.

Comment: When I said what you wrote was correct, I meant grammatically, syntactically, and understandably. I wasn't referring to the opinion expressed, about which I have no opinion.